# populating object data from flaskSQLAlchemy into wtfforms fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to populate data from User model like username and email into the form so the the admin can update them using the user_id passed in the route to query the user. But i'm doing a custom validation in the form to check if the field didn't change so it won't raise an error that username is taken.

Currently i'm using `g` global variable offered by Flask to match the user obj data queried in the route to be passed in the form validation function. Any way i can do this better ??

Below is the code for the Form:

```
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    status = SelectField("Account Status", choices=[(True, "Verified"), (False, "Not Verified")], coerce=bool, validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Update")

def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != g.username:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("That username is taken, please choose a different one.")

def validate_email(self, email):
    if email.data != g.email:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("That email is taken, please choose a different one.")
```

This is the code for the route:

```
admin.route("/admin_panel/update_user/<int:user_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@admin_login_required
def update_user(user_id):

    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()

    g.username = user.username
    g.email = user.email

    updateUserForm = UpdateUserForm()
    updateUserForm.username.data = user.username
    updateUserForm.email.data = user.email
    print("this is first one" + str(updateUserForm.status.data))

    if updateUserForm.validate_on_submit():
        user.username = updateUserForm.username.data
        user.email = updateUserForm.email.data
        user.verified = updateUserForm.status.data
        print("this is second one" + str(updateUserForm.status.data))
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Account updated!", 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('admin.admin_panel'))

    return render_template("admin/update_user.html", title="Update User", updateUserForm=updateUserForm)
```

Not that i can't use current user as that the admin logged in

Comment: Can you show the code you are currently using, so it will be easier to understand what you want to do and thus provide you with the help you need

Comment: Oh, sorry for that.

Comment: There is something I can not understand. Who records a user in the database? Is it the admin or the user himself ?. If the user does it himself, what is the admin supposed to do?

Comment: Another thing is that your text is quite difficult to understand. Please, can you take a few minutes to rephrase it correctly by providing as much details as you can about exactly what you want to do? For example you can show what are the successive steps involved in the execution of your code.

Comment: So, the user can sign in / sign up / edit profile;. while the admin can edit on the users profiles as well which is what I'm trying to achieve, the case here that iam trying to make a validation that checks if the admin is changing for ex. the username of the users it would say either it is taken or not and if didn't change it won't say that its taken as long it is the same user the admin editing. thank u for ur support